# Will importing classes with embed meta tags without instantiating the class load them?

Tags: actionscript-3, embedded-resource, starling-framework

I'm building an air mobile app and want to load a different set of graphics for SD and HD devices, I have my resources classes setup as follows:

SD graphics

```
package view.graphics 
{
    public class MainMenuGraphicsSD extends GraphicsResource
    {
        [Embed(source = "../../../lib/graphics/mainmenu/logo.png")]
        public static const logo:Class;
    }   
}
```

And then the HD

```
package view.graphics 
{
    public class MainMenuGraphicsHD extends GraphicsResource
    {
        [Embed(source = "../../../lib/graphics/mainmenu/logoHD.png")]
        public static const logo:Class;
    }   
}
```

And then in the main menu class I have at the top

```
import view.graphics.MainMenuGraphicsHD;
import view.graphics.MainMenuGraphicsSD;
```

I pass the class Name to the asset manager to enqueue the items inside, and preload them...

```
Assets.getInstance().assets.enqueue( isHD ? MainMenuGraphicsHD : MainMenuGraphicsSD);
```

would all the assets get embedded but only the relevant definition referenced or should it work how I want it to and only load the relevant resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code both assets will be embedded, and only the relevant asset will be instantiated. If you want to make these resources externally loaded in order to reduce the SWF size, you need to play with `Loader`s and then reference the content via `loader.content`. You may, for example, compile two SWFs containing assets only, one for SD and one for HD, load the relevant SWF once the resolution is established, and instantiate classes from there using [the way described in this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467622/how-can-i-instantiate-class-from-a-swf).

Comment: They are being compiled for mobile, so I assume both assets will be embedded into the ipa or apk, but will both sets of assets be loaded into RAM at runtime?

Comment: No, only the referred asset will be instantiated aka loaded into RAM. See, bitmaps take a lot of RAM space while embedded assets usually take a lot less (class description plus a byte array of a JPG/PNG is a lot less than an expanded `BitmapData`), so the actual conversion from asset to bitmap is only done for the selected asset.